# How to override TypeScript built-in variable definitions

Tags: typescript

I'm writing code that uses an `AudioContext`, as defined at [lib.es6.d.ts#L7272](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L7272).

The [latest version of the spec](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioContext), which is implemented in Chrome, allows an extra option to the constructor, an options object.

My question is, can I override the existing global definition of the constructor to allow the options object?

I constantly get `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

When I try to redefine the constructor, like this:

```
declare var AudioContext: {
    prototype: AudioContext;
    new(options: {}): AudioContext;
};
```

I get

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'AudioContext' must be of type `{ new (): AudioContext; prototype: AudioContext; }`, but here has type `{ new (options: {}): AudioContext; prototype: AudioContext; }`